# Salesforce Data Extension still available after changing the Data Retention Policy

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I sent an email to a Salesforce Report and, once I changed the Data Retention Policy to the Salesforce Data Extension that is autogenerated with the send (to one day instead of 5 days, by default), the Data Extension is still available.

[image]

Comment: How long ago did you edit this?  If you edit this today, the depreciation does not run exactly 24 hours after you edit it.   The deprecation runs daily and can vary each day based on volume of other processes and data being deprecated.  If it's set to be deleted tomorrow (2019-07-20 00:00:00), this will run in the morning of 7/21 I believe.  Retention can also only be edited in Contact Builder for these data extensions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, the Salesforce Data Extension was automatically deleted. It didn't take exactly 24 hours but a couple of hours more.

Answer (score 3):

Currently the data retention policies for Salesforce Data Extension cannot be modified through Email Studio. To update the retention policy so that changes are retained, it should be done through Contact Builder.

Comment: What do you mean they can't be modified? They recently released a feature to do just that. Are you saying it doesn't work? I've been having this same issue with the same type of test using 1 day.